# Does hibernate provide a datasource jdni url?

Tags: jdbc, datasource, jndi

I know that application servers can typically provide a connection to your database via JNDI.  Is it possible for hibernate running in Java SE to provide a JNDI url/datasource like an application container such as Tomcat/Glassfish/Jetty would normally?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html#d5e199) it seems like it should be possible. You just have to provide a few parameters:

> Important Hibernate properties for JNDI datasources
>
> hibernate.connection.datasource (required)
>
> hibernate.jndi.url
>
> hibernate.jndi.class
>
> hibernate.connection.username
>
> hibernate.connection.password

Comment: I was referring to providing a JNDI URL via hibernate (for a 3rd party library that needs it) NOT using a JNDI URL for hibernate to acquire a connection.

Comment: In other words you want Hibernate to be a JNDI provider?

Comment: Yes, how can Hibernate be a JNDI provider?